# ReactJS: How to access an array of form input children?

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, input, reactjs

I have the following form which I would like to have a dynamic number of player name input fields, passed to `PlayerSelect` as `props.numPlayers`, and would like it to read the user input from each of those fields and pass the names as an array to `this.props.setPlayers`, which is a callback passed from the parent component.

I am trying to find the right way to access the `PlayerNameInput` components from the parent, as following doesn't seem to be working:

```
var PlayerSelect = React.createClass({
  getPlayers: function() {
    var playerNames = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++) {
      var playerName = this.players[i].getDOMNode().value.trim();
      playerNames.push(playerName);
    }
    this.props.setPlayers(playerNames);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.players = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.numPlayers; i++) {
      this.players.push(<PlayerNameInput />);
    }
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <form className="player-select">
          <ol className="players">
            {this.players}
          </ol>
          <button onClick={this.getPlayers}>Done</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var PlayerNameInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <li><input type="text"/></li>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ref` to access DOM node:

```
var PlayerSelect = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() { return { names: [] } },
  getPlayers: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var playerNames = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.numPlayers; i++) {
      var playerName = this.refs['player-' + i].getDOMNode().value.trim();
      playerNames.push(playerName);
    }
    this.setState({ names: playerNames });
  },
  render: function() {
    var players = []
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.numPlayers; i++) {
      players.push(
          <li key={'player-' + i}>
              <input ref={ 'player-' + i } type="text"/>
          </li>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <form className="player-select">
          <ol className="players">
            {players}
          </ol>
          <button onClick={this.getPlayers}>Done</button>
        </form>
        <div>{ this.state.names.join(', ') }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/1723/)

Also remember:

- when you create array of elements every single one has to have unique `key`
- don't modify props of your component to communicate with outside modules. Use some other library which provides models to communicate between components, for example Backbone or Flux ( in my example for simplicity I just saved collected player names to components state ).